# Pure Javascript to detect SPA DOM ready and page change

Tags: javascript, dom-events, single-page-application

I need to fire a function when the DOM ready or page view changed on single-page applications, here is my code and it works for the first time the user visits the site (DOM ready), but it didn't work when a user switches SPA pages (view changed).

I need a common method for most websites and SPA projects since this code needs to be executed on each of our client's websites(sort of like Google Analytics tracking code), and this code need executed every time when the end-users load or switch the pages. Is there any pure Javascript that can detect when the SPA changes pages?

```
function docReady(fn) {
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}

docReady(function() {
    _AcodeInit();
});

function _AcodeInit()
{
...
}
```

Comment: That depends heavily on how you're routing, but you can always fire a custom event on window or document whenever you want.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the reply, Is there a common method for most websites and SPA projects? Because this code needs to be executed on each of our client's websites

Comment: What SPA framework are you using? AngularJS, Angular2+ (TypeScript), React? Vue?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the *question itself seems really odd*. In an SPA generally page transitions will only happen when you allow them to happen, so it seems very strange that you would need something to tell you. Most of the client side routers I can think of have explicit APIs for page transitions, the only time you would have something external would be e.g. the user clicking the back button. My current view is part of the state of my app, I never need something to tell me, but as I said you could fire an event I guess. What are you using for routing?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the reply, I need a common method for most websites and SPA projects, since this code needs to be executed on each of our client's websites.

Comment: @JaredSmith I’m sorry that maybe I didn’t express it clearly. I need this code to be executed on the client’s website, including the SPA applications. They have many routing methods, so I need a general method so that when users load and switch pages, our code can be executed again every time they load a new view or page.

Comment: @tvvocold Ahhh ok I get it now. You have to detect the change that *someone else* initiated, you don't have control over the site. V1p3r's answer is pretty good.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the reply, and yes that answer is good but could you have a look at my code? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QJrJrtjCPM How to make history.pushState function to run after the DOM ready? (Currently I had set a timeout but I think it's not a good solution)

Comment: @tvvocold Did you find the generic solution or not

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Listening to Changes in URL**

As SPAs use routing, you could ideally listen to url changes.

One crude way of doing this is to keep polling using setInterval and track the changes to the url. If the url has changed you could run your handler. However this is wasteful.

Given the lack of options you can listen to all events which could cause transitions, (e.g. mouse clicks, keyboard Enter/Space key press etc.) and in the handler check if the url has changed. Use requestAnimationFrame so that we don't execute handler prematurely.

```
let currentUrl = location.href;
const checkPageTransition = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (currentUrl !== location.href) {
            console.log("url changed");
        }
        currentUrl = location.href;
    }, true);
};


document.body.addEventListener("click", checkPageTransition);
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    if (e.code === "Enter" || e.code === "Space") checkPageTransition()
});
```

**Option 2: Listening to popstate event**

If you are using modern SPAs, they would most likely be using history.pushState and history.popState to manage routing. We could then listen to the window.popstate event. But there are limitations to this event.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

> Note: Calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by performing a browser action, such as clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript), when navigating between two history entries for the same document.

However we can monkey patch the history.pushState function so that it always fires the history.onpushstate function.

```
(function(history) { 
    var pushState = history.pushState; 
    history.pushState = function(state) { 
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") 
        { 
            history.onpushstate({ 
                state: state 
            }); 
        } 
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments); 
    } 
})(window.history);
```

You would need to similarly patch the replaceState function as well.

Comment: ". However there is no generic way which will notify us of this change." - that's not true. You can subscribe to the `popstate` and `hashchange` events on `window`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate - and while the `history` methods don't raise the events directly, you could override those methods as well.

Comment: @Dai Yes. Monkey patching to the rescue. I've updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: hello, why it would fire twice or even more when I switch the SPA page view?  here is my code right after your monkey patched history.pushState function : `window.onpopstate = history.onpushstate = function() {_AcodeInit(); };  ` How to make '_AcodeInit();' fire only once when the DOM ready or SPA view changed?